# Create custom facet for Sitecore SXA search filter

Tags: sxa, content-search, search-facet

I have to apply the SXA search Checklist filter component on a search result by the product type (which is a single line text field).

Can anyone please provide any information or useful links on how to create a custom facet to show all the product types in the filter?

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2018/07/sitecore-sxa-search-overview-pages.html

Adding the filter to the page is not that hard - it's a standard component. Getting the facet that is used by the filter component right is a bit more tricky.

If you want to have a facet on a single line text you should use a `List Facet`. Create your facet in the facets folder "Tenant/Site/Settings/Facets/" and set the `Field Name`. This has to be the lowercase name of the index field that is used for the facet (your product type). Check your index to get the correct name...

Next step: go to "Tenant/Site/Data/Search/Checklist Filter" and create a new Checklist filter. Select your facet and adapt texts as needed.

This filter item will be the datasource for the Checklist component that you can put on your page.

Comment: I tried to sthe same but not able 2 do .Is there any config needs to be added?

Comment: No.. maybe try to explain what you did and what is not working

Comment: I created a list facet under /sitecore/content/Settings/Facets.This facet is used in the check list filter .In the field name field I tried to give the solrindex name (did nt work),field name (did nt work),then also i tried to give field name with lower case.Still I am not getting the product types in the filter list.Please suggest

Comment: Check the search log file to find the query that is performed when the facet is requested. To do this, get the url that is requested to fetch the facet data from the browser (dev tools) so you can do that request separately.  The query in the log should tell you more.. you can use that in the solr admin to test it until you get it right.

Comment: What did you use as solr index field name?