# How To Create Custom Hierarchical Tree Search Filter

Tags: search-facet, sxa-search

I already tried the solution in the following [question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27162/create-custom-facet-for-sitecore-sxa-search-filter) but it didn't help it only explains how to create OOB filters.

I'm using sitecore 10.1 SXA and I need a way to view hierarchical filter in a search page(am using SXA OOB search).

For Example:
I have checklist location filter with below values

[image]

I want to display all countries and cities like the above photo.

Does anyone knows how to create for example custom search facet/custom tree filter to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Content Search API and apply FacetOn() method on IQueryable like this:

```
context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(predicate).FacetOn(x => x[“Propery1Name”], 1).FacetOn(x => x[“Propery2Name”], 1).GetFacets();
```

While: **Propery1Name** is your Country field and **Propery2Name** is your City field

You can reach more information in this article: [here](https://ankitjoshi2409.wordpress.com/2017/12/31/faceted-search-with-sitecore/)